# What is named this structure?

Tags: python

Some days ago I saw this Python `string` structure:

```
str = (
'this is a very'
'long string too'
'for sure ...'
)
```

I'm interested how is named this structure? It's not `list` or `tuple`.

Sorry for maybe simple question but I tried to found in official Python manual and couldn't. It would be nice if you attach link to manual.

Comment: It is just a string.

Comment: That is just a string. The parts are concatonated.

Comment: also suggest you never use `str` as an identifier, its a reserved word.

Comment: And the brackets are a syntax hack so that you don't need line continuations ...

Comment: @AndrewAllaire I know it, just I write as example. :)

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Thanks a lot, It help me.